# How can I make the iRobot Create turn by the specified angle in Webots?

Tags: python, webots, c

I am trying to use the iRobot Create in Webots for a project on vacuum cleaning. I am impressed by the fact that Webots contains the `create.wbt` world as well as default controllers for robot and supervisor by default. Great Work!

However, I noticed that the default `turn(angle)` function in the `create_avoid_obstacles` controller turns the robot by less than the specified angle. It is best visible if the angle is set to 90 or 180 degrees. One quick fix I came up with is to multiply the angle by a factor around 1.2 before passing it to the function. But I cannot identify the exact factor needed to produce the desired behavior.

I checked the formulas used in the `turn(angle)` function, and for me, they seem to be correct. I also checked whether the parameters match the PROTO file of the robot, which seems to be the case as well. Maybe it is a problem with the resolution of the position sensor?

The default controller of iRobot Create is written in C and below is the source code of the `turn(angle)` function.

```
#define WHEEL_RADIUS 0.031
#define AXLE_LENGTH 0.271756
#define ENCODER_RESOLUTION 507.9188
static void turn(double angle) {
  stop();
  double l_offset = wb_position_sensor_get_value(left_position_sensor);
  double r_offset = wb_position_sensor_get_value(right_position_sensor);
  step();
  double neg = (angle < 0.0) ? -1.0 : 1.0;
  wb_motor_set_velocity(left_motor, neg * HALF_SPEED);
  wb_motor_set_velocity(right_motor, -neg * HALF_SPEED);
  double orientation;
  do {
    double l = wb_position_sensor_get_value(left_position_sensor) - l_offset;
    double r = wb_position_sensor_get_value(right_position_sensor) - r_offset;
    double dl = l * WHEEL_RADIUS;                 // distance covered by left wheel in meter
    double dr = r * WHEEL_RADIUS;                 // distance covered by right wheel in meter
    orientation = neg * (dl - dr) / AXLE_LENGTH;  // delta orientation in radian
    step();
  } while (orientation < neg * angle);
  stop();
  step();
}
```

Since my project will ultimately be in Python, I translated the code from C to Python below, but the problem persists in both programming languages.

```
WHEEL_RADIUS = 0.031
AXLE_LENGTH = 0.271756
ENCODER_RESOLUTION = 507.9188
def turn(angle):
    stop()
    l_offset = left_position_sensor.getValue()
    r_offset = right_position_sensor.getValue()
    step()
    angle_sign = -1.0 if angle < 0.0 else 1.0
    left_motor.setVelocity(angle_sign * HALF_SPEED)
    right_motor.setVelocity(-angle_sign * HALF_SPEED)
    while True:
        l = left_position_sensor.getValue() - l_offset
        r = right_position_sensor.getValue() - r_offset
        dl = l * WHEEL_RADIUS                                # distance covered by left wheel in meter
        dr = r * WHEEL_RADIUS                                # distance covered by right wheel in meter
        orientation = angle_sign * (dl - dr) / AXLE_LENGTH;  # delta orientation in radian
        step()
        if orientation >= angle_sign * angle:
            break
    stop()
    step()
```

I am thankful for any help on this issue.